# Programmatically moving to other view results in black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I'm using this code to programmatically move from my main screen (Login page) to the view behind it, but it gives a black screen;

```
LandingController *landingController = [[LandingController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:landingController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've included the `LandingController.h` file into my `ViewController.h` and it also doesn't  give any errors.

When I remove my Storyboard ID from my `LandingController` (which isn't referred to) in the above code, I get this message:

```
/Users/allendar/Desktop/iOS Apps/#HIDDEN# App/#HIDDEN# App/Base.lproj/Main_iPad.storyboard: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
```

I'm assuming this has something to do that I only call the associated Controller for the View, whereas it doesn't actually instantiate the View's internals.

I already tried some other examples by triggering the Storyboard ID of the `LandingController`, but it either gives errors or just does nothing (like this code does).

Any ideas how I can invoke the View itself when triggering its Controller, or either doing it through the Storyboard ID?

Comment: If you're using storyboards - why not use a segue to go to another view and call [self performSequeWithIdentifier@"segueIdentifier"]; ?If you're going back to a view controller - you could use unwind segues.

Comment: The `Navigational Controller` is needed, and it clutters my Login screen; which I prefer not to have :)

Comment: So landingController is embedded in a UINavigationController? and the view that presents it is not?

Comment: No the targeted view is a blank view too, with no navigational construction attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    UIStoryboard *storybboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOURSTORYBOARD" bundle:nil];
LandingController * landingController  = [storybboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STORYBOARD ID"];
[self presentViewController: landingController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your view controller from the storyboard instead of doing alloc->init. Give your view controller an identifier in your storyboard and load it as follows:

```
[self presentViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"]];
```

Comment: There's a parse-error in your example. But it works after fixing it. So +1 too :)

Comment: I fixed it. I'm not using a Mac now, XCode does really help sometimes! :D